# trouble debugging and running sample android project

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I installed the Android 2.2 SDK (2.2 is the version i have on my smartphone). I've tried running the NotePad sample project as an Android project. Here is what happens: the emulator loads, but when I click on the app, the screen goes blank. There are no errors being thrown. Has anyone else run into this problem? If so, how have you fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press run, the emulator loads AND the application should automatically open and run. Also, make sure there are no errors with the code itself.

If all else fails, try a new/ different SDK and make sure the app has no errors during it's installation into the SDK. Look at the Console and LogCat to make sure that there are no errors the emulator runs.

Comment: @Kurty--There are no errors in the new SDK that I tried and no errors when the mulator runs. MY device is not being shown in DDMS or in the command prompt (`adb devices`). Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not to sure about what the problem is then... Have you tried running a project of your own or creating something like "Hello, World" to see if it works properly?

Comment: @Kurty--I've written a working "Hello, World" program in the emulator, I just can't get it onto my phone. The problem seems to be in eclipse not recognizing my device..

Comment: Hmm.. so you want to get the application on your phone to debug and run right? I'm not specifically sure on how to fix your current problem but there is an alternative. Since you can run your emulator, you can debug and stuff using the LogCat and Console, there's no need of getting it on your phone. The alternative is that you can Export your code into an APK file in which you can then download onto your phone, and then uninstall or replace once you have finished with it. I know that convenience wise, connecting eclipse to your phone is quicker but this is all I know of so far.